# Распределение задач при совместной разработке

Tags: git, разработка-игр, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура

Собрались с другом написать небольшую игрушку (что бы набить руку в совместной разработке), зарегались на bitbucket как деловые и тут начались нешуточные такие коллизии... Какой то слишком большой оверхед получается на устранение конфликтов. В итоге решили по отдельности делать.

Каким образом лучше всего произвести распределение задач между разработчиками, таким образом, чтобы они **мешали как можно меньше друг другу**? А то например скрипт для 3D объекта поменял один человек, а сам объект - другой человек (вообще например его удалил)

Т.е. от чего отталкиваться? Слабосвязанный код? Особенная архитектура? В общем у меня каша в голове, хотелось бы узнать в каком хоть бы направлении следовать.

Comment: Простой вариант - делать разные вещи и договориться об этом заранее. Типа "я делаю первый уровень", "а я тогда второй уровень \ ачивки прикручу \ музыку попилю".

Comment: При командной разработке разные люди занимаются разными частями приложения, чтобы свести к минимуму конфликты, как систем контроля версий, так и социальные.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы вдвоем работаете над проектом в системе контроля версий или же вы просто участвуете в развитии open source проекта, то обычно это происходит следующим образом: участник делает fork репозитория в свой профиль и начинает работать над ним или же, если у каждого участника есть доступ к репозитория с возможностью редактирования (обычно такое бывает когда вы работаете с командой над собственным проектом) то каждый участник работает на своей отдельной ветке или на ветке разработки(обычно dev). Чтобы не возникало проблем и коллизий обычно делятся на различный функционал. Но если два участника работают над одним и тем же файлом одновременно, то обычно это происходит у каждого участника на отдельных ветках. Например, Иван и Николай работают над файлом Msin.java и каждый пытается его модернизировать/упростить/раздуть и потом хвалятся своими успехами делая pull request в основную ветку (пусть будет master) после этого, при удовлетворении pull request, мы можем увидеть какие файлы были изменены более подробно вплоть до добавления и удаления строк. Это очень сильно позволяет выявить самый лучший алгоритм работы внутри файла или же сказать одному из участников, что пусть лучше он работает над своей частью кода и не помогает вам больше. Вот примерно так.